# Remove html5test.com website data in Safari Technology Preview

Tags: safari, macos

I am trying to remove all website data from Safari Technology Preview but after using the "Remove all website data" button the list of websites gets filled with html5test.com and i cannot find the way to remove it:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking it and pressing Remove? Do you have html5test.com open behind the preferences window?

Comment: obviously I did try clicking and pressing remove, but it didn't work. the url was not open behind the preferences window.

Comment: Now it is happening again but with ebay.es (databases)